# Determining If any log File Exists in storage log folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Currently laravel is writing log to default logs folder in storage/logs.

The logs folder also contains a .gitignore file.

How can i determine if  ***ANY***  `*.log` file exists in logs folder?

Comment: From your question I can not understand why you would not be able to simply do a `ls` from your `storage/logs` directory. Try this `cd storage/logs && ls | grep log`

Comment: @Bishal Checking log file is test progress and should perform dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it with `glob` function :

```
$result = glob (base_path() . '/storage/logs/*.log');
if(count($result)) {
    // log files exist
}
```

note that `base_path()` is a laravel helper to get the path of project root directory.

Comment: damet garm dadash

Answer (score 0):

@Joseph Rback Finally, Laravel has it's own logs, whose purpose are to record errors|info|debug and their stack traces, if any are given. These are the most interesting/important logs, and the ones you configure within Laravel/Lumen. These usually exist in **path/to/laravel/storage/logs/laragel.log**.